# How to use custom third party library in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, tcpdf

I want to use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) library in my ZF2 project. I have the source of library but it is incompatible with Zend Framework 2 namespace (not PSR-0). How to include it in the project? If there are any way to convert it with ZF2 compatible.

If there is a way to use the library as it is then please show the process (where to place library source and how to include it).

Please do not suggest ZendPdf as an alternative.
Thanks

Comment: You can try to use zend's namespacer commandline tool to convert that old TCPPDF library to more autoloader & namespace friendly. https://github.com/zendframework/Namespacer Without namespacing, autoloading and PSR-0 like standard-aware coding, integration 3rd party libraries like this would be hard.

Answer (score 6):

So one way to do this with the command line tool that foozy mentioned, but this leads to altering some one else's code and who wants that headache. You can can also do this with Composer using the [autoload:classmap directive](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) since it is a class even though it's not PSR-0.

Basically, you would place the TCPDF files somewhere convenient (vendor folder, lib folder, etc.) and then add the autoload directive to composer.json like so:

```
{
  "autoload": {
      "classmap": ["vendor/tcpdf"]
  }
}
```

Assuming you placed the tcpdf folder in the vendor folder and that the TCPDF class is in the root of the tcpdf folder. Then you run `php composer.phar update` . Composer will then add that folder as a source location to the autoloader function it registers with the SPL autoloder.

Then where ever you want to use the TCPDF class you would do `$pdf = new \TCPDF()`.

NOTE: I'm not 100% on the path being relative to the project root, composer.phar, or the vendor folder.

Comment: $pdf = new \TCPdF() should be $pdf = new \TCPDF().

Comment: I shall thank you the autoload functionality I did not know about saved me quite some troube ;)

Comment: That's a great shot +1